# Expected value of $g(x, y)$ without having their joint distribution

Tags: probability

For two random variables: $X$, $Y$. If their marginal distributions are given $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$ and $g(x, y)$ is some function of $X$ and $Y$. Can I get the expected value of $g(x, y)$ if I know their covariance matrix but I do not have their joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x, y)$

Comment: By "covariance matrix", do you mean the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, which is just one number?

Comment: no I mean [Var(x) Cov(x, y); Cov(x, y) Var(y)]

Answer (score 5):

Here's an explicit counterexample:$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb E}$

Consider the function $g(x, y) = x^2 y^2$ and the marginal distributions $X \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$, $Y \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$, and no covariance: $\E[X Y] = 0$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so that $\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\left( \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$,
then
$$
\E\left[g(X, Y)\right]
= \E\left[X^2 Y^2\right]
= \E\left[X^2\right] \E\left[Y^2\right]
= 1
.$$

But consider instead the case $Y = Z X$, where $Z \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(\{-1, 1\})$ is independent.

We can check that the marginal distribution of $Y$ is still correct:
\begin{align}
     \Pr(Y \le y)
  &= \Pr(Z X \le y)
\\&= \Pr(Z = 1) \Pr(X \le y \mid Z = 1) + \Pr(Z = -1) \Pr(X \ge -y \mid Z = -1)
\\&= \frac12 \Pr(X \le y \mid Z = 1) + \frac12 \Pr(X \ge -y \mid Z = -1)
\\&= \frac12 \Pr(X \le y) + \frac12 \Pr(X \ge -y)
\\&= \Pr(X \le y)
\end{align}
because $Z$ is independent of $X$ and the distribution of $X$ is symmetric about 0.

We also have that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated:
$$
\E[X Y] - \E[X] \E[Y]
= \E[X (Z X)] - 0
= \E[X^2] \E[Z]
= 1 \cdot 0
= 0
.$$

But the expectation of $g$ is different than the other case:
$$
\E\left[g(X, Y)\right]
= \E\left[X^2 Y^2\right]
= \E\left[X^2 (Z X)^2\right]
= \E\left[X^4\right] \E\left[Z^2\right]
= 3
.$$

---

Here's the one case where you *can* compute it:
suppose that $g$ is of the form
$$g(x, y) = g_x(x) + g_y(y) + \alpha x y + \beta.$$
Then
$$
\E[g(X, Y)]
= \E[g_x(X)] + \E[g_y(Y)] + \alpha \E[X Y] + \beta
,$$
so you can compute the expectations of $g_x$ and $g_y$ using the marginal distribution, and you know $\E[X Y] = \rho + \E[X] \E[Y]$.

Comment: But when we put Y=ZX, How do we know that X, Y are still uncorrelated?

Comment: @AbdoSaiedAnwar I added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There may be special cases, but in general, If you could get any $E[g(x,y)]$, then you could get any joint moment. And, that should reveal the joint distribution, and I don't think you can do this using only covariance matrix.

Thinking in 1D, if you have any moment, you can write the moment generating function, which lead to [characteristic function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#/Introduction), which also lead to PDF. In 2D, if you have any joint moment, that should in some way similarly lead to joint PDF.

Comment: "that should reveal the joint distribution" -- that's only going to be sufficient to determine the joint distribution if the MGF exists in a neighborhood of 0.